# Python Regex - Reference first line on every match, until the start of a new group

Tags: python, regex

**Sample text:**

```
This is HeaderA
 Line 1
 Line 2
 Line 3
 Line 4
 Line 5
This is HeaderB
 Line 1
 Line 2
```

**Intended result:**

```
HeaderA1 HeaderA2 HeaderA3 HeaderA4 HeaderA5

HeaderB1, HeaderB2
```

**Regex Attempts:**

`(?:^This is (?P<H>HeaderB)\s) (Line (?P<L>\d)\s)*?`

- Matches only the Header 'H' and 1st  'L' Line

`(?:^This is (?P<H>HeaderB)\s)? (Line (?P<L>\d)\s)*?`

- manage to match multiple 'L' Lines however, only first 2 line are of the same match, not the subsequent L lines does not reference the Header capture group.

I tried other attempts to adjust the regex but ended up screwing up the expression. I have limited experience with regex, so I am not entirely sure if it is possible to get the desired output.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a single regex. Which flag did you used for your attempts? Could you add your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mix of regex and substitutions with `format`.

It is assumed that below a Header you **always** have a Line i

```
import re
text = """This is HeaderA
 Line 1
 Line 2
 Line 3
 Line 4
 Line 5
This is HeaderB
 Line 1
 Line 2"""

ordered_matches = [] # global

def custom_match(m, all_matches=ordered_matches):
    p = m.group(0)
    if p.isdigit():
        all_matches[-1] += [p]
    else:
        all_matches += [[p]]
    return '' # doesn't matter

r = re.sub(r'([A-Z0-9]+)$', custom_match, text, flags=re.M)

for m in ordered_matches:
    print(('Header{}{{}} '.format(m[0]) * (len(m)-1)).format(*m[1:]))
```

Output

```
HeaderA1 HeaderA2 HeaderA3 HeaderA4 HeaderA5 
HeaderB1 HeaderB2
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you're trying to combine the `Header(A|B)` with the integers in the following lines. With the given output, it's probably easier to work with simple `split()` operations instead of re.

```py
for group in text.split('This is ')[1:]:
    header, *lines = group.splitlines()
    print(*[header+line.split()[-1] for line in lines])
```

**Output:**

```
HeaderA1 HeaderA2 HeaderA3 HeaderA4 HeaderA5
HeaderB1 HeaderB2
```